# Optimizing lengthy SQL query for datatable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to retrieve all the logs of logins on the basis of date. In addition I need all the functionality of JQuery-datatable sorting and searching in it! I have worked on many queries and datatables but this one is tougher than I thought.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_login_logs]
(
    @sp_start_date DATETIME,
    @sp_end_date DATETIME,
    @sp_offset INT,
    @sp_count INT,
    @sp_search VARCHAR(MAX),
    @sp_sort INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT table1.email,table1.city,table1.latitude,table1.longitude,table1.first_log,
    table1.last_log,table1.platform,table1.app 
    FROM (SELECT ll.email,
       ISNULL(ll.city,'') city,
       ll.latitude,
       ll.longitude,
       (SELECT min(insertdate)
       FROM [LoginLog]
       WHERE email=ll.email) AS first_log,
       ll.insertdate AS last_log,
       CASE
           WHEN platform LIKE '%iPhone%'
                OR platform LIKE '%Darwin%'
                OR platform LIKE '%iPad%'
                OR platform LIKE '%iOS%' THEN 'iPhone'
           ELSE CASE
                    WHEN platform LIKE '%Android%'
                         OR platform LIKE '%Apache%' THEN 'Android'
                    ELSE 'iPhone'
                END
       END AS platform,
       CASE
           WHEN app IS NULL THEN 'Consumer'
           ELSE App
       END AS app
    FROM [LoginLog] ll
    WHERE id =
        (SELECT max(id)
         FROM [LoginLog] ll2
         WHERE ll2.email =ll.email
         AND
            (ll2.email like '%'+@sp_search+'%'OR
            ll2.city like '%'+@sp_search+'%'OR
            ll2.latitude like '%'+@sp_search+'%'OR
            ll2.longitude like '%'+@sp_search+'%'
            )
         )
         AND ll.email<>'' AND ll.email<>'(null)'
         AND ll.insertdate>@sp_start_date AND ll.insertdate<@sp_end_date
         AND loginsucess=1 and isnull(Country, 'United States')='United States'
    ) AS table1
    WHERE(
            table1.first_log like '%'+@sp_search+'%'OR
            table1.last_log like '%'+@sp_search+'%'OR
            table1.platform like '%'+@sp_search+'%'OR
            table1.app like '%'+@sp_search+'%'          
        )
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 01 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.email END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 01 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.email END DESC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 02 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.city END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 02 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.city END DESC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 03 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.latitude END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 03 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.latitude END DESC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 04 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.longitude END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 04 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.longitude END DESC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 05 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.first_log END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 05 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.first_log END DESC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 06 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.last_log END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 06 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.last_log END DESC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 07 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.platform END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 07 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.platform END DESC,      
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 08 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 1) THEN table1.app END ASC,
        CASE WHEN (@sp_sort%100 = 08 and ((@sp_sort%1000)/100) = 0) THEN table1.app END DESC        
    OFFSET @sp_offset ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @sp_count ROWS Only
END
```

This works fine but consumes a lot of memory and time... Can't wait for 5 minutes with more than millions of records in it.

This is my table in case any one needs :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoginLog](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Platform] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Latitude] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Longitude] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ipaddress] [nvarchar](55) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [APP] [varchar](55) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](55) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC (tags and title edited)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Yes! Its my mistakes. Ty for correcting.

Comment: So the actual problem is: your SQL has a performance issue. Its not clear how "I need all the functionality of jquery-datatable sorting and searching in it" relates to this piece of code.

Comment: These kinds of dynamic stored proc's usually suffer from _parameter sniffing_

Comment: The query as it is requires table scans and probably more constructs that perform badly. This looks like a legitimate case for constructing a dynamic SQL statement, to have a SQL statement with as few unecessary constructs as possible.

Comment: Begin by recognizing that the root cause of your performance problems is that your data is currently grossly ***non-relational***. And, your performance problems are only going to get worse with time until you restructure your data model to be relational. Until then, you will have to use dynamic SQL to get the best performance possible with your terrible data model.

Comment: The presence of all those '%value%' patterns in your query demonstrates that your data columns are non-atomic, and thus you fail Zero'th normal form.

Comment: You would be far better off to parse all those fields just one, on creation, and store the results in a proper relational table.

Comment: do you have index on insertdate field?

Comment: Give me little time.I'll get back!

Comment: My Inner query takes hardly 3 seconds even when I remove the startdate and enddate in where clause, but reserves memory for few thousands of records.I never use 'case when-then' condition in where clause. I think memory is the root cause of it.

Comment: Searching work fine when date range is between few days. When it goes above a month it executes for ever!

Comment: @TT. you are correct! But how do I resolve it with out redesigning the table?

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep referring to memory. It's quite tricky to work out how much memory a specific query takes. It's not normally something you worry about initially. So forget about memory. I suggest you post the query plan for slow and fast results. I would guess your SP has a cached query plan which works well for certain parameters and badly for others. But in the end, yes you need to redesign for a relational data model.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoginLog](
 [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Platform] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Latitude] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Longitude] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [InsertDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [APP] [varchar](55) NULL,
 [Country] [varchar](55) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)   and yes my database is relational

Comment: Sorry I'm mixing up terminology incorrectly. Your database is relational but your data model (the tables in it) are possibly not 3rd normal form. For example your table is basically just a big free text excel sheet. You might see some improvement's if for example you spun off `Platform`, `City` etc. into other tables.... or you might not. You basically need to look at your query plan and find the worst offending piece. Certainly LIKE searches with a leading `%` ring alarm bells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not a lot you can do. THe problem is that the case in the sort if going to kill any optimization the sql server may do. You should look at the query plan, and add a with recompile, but at the end of the day - that query is not going to work efficient. Dynamic SQL is the only efficient way to go here - either from the client, or by string manipulation in the sp followed by a execute command to execute the SQL string.

And obviously the non sargeable elements kill  the use of any index - at the end, whoever designed the database did an extremely incompetent job here. There is no proper way to query it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments section your stored procedure has many problems, so it is hard to point at one thing and say: "Here, that's the problem, fix it and you're good".

I'll list a few things that jump out to me:

> The derived table within a derived table within a derived table mess.

Compilers are usually good at optimizing a query, provided that the query is not too deep in terms of derived tables/subqueries (ie not too complex). If your query is becoming too deep you should consider populating derived tables in temporary tables (suitably indexed if needed).

I know that is a very broad statement and it is hard to determine when exactly you should apply this way of working. As usual the proof is in eating the pudding.

> Forcing table scans wrecks performance.

For instance, you have a subquery that determines the `MAX(id) FROM [LoginLog] ll2`. In that subquery your WHERE clause has the condition `ll2.email=ll.email`. When there is no suitable INDEX on `LoginLog.email` this will force a table scan on `LoginLog` to find the corresponding email address.

The clause has an additional complex lookup with a series of OR'ed LIKE statements that will force a table scan. There is no boolean short-circuiting in SQL Server so even if you provide an INDEX on `LoginLog.email`, there could be a table scan to determine the state of the other conditions.

You can see these scans if you include an [Actual Execution Plan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms189562.aspx) for your query.

> Trying to do it all in one query

A query that *does it all* is usually too complex to be executed quickly. Consider splitting up the use cases, and create a simpler query for each such use case. In general, non-complex queries with few parameters will execute quicker.

> Parameter Sniffing

I'm not going to go in detail, there are plenty of essays online that explain this (eg [this one](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/) that pops up first in my search engine). This "parameter sniffing" can hurt stored procedure performance. The first time your stored procedure is run, the SQL Server compiler will create an execution plan that is optimized for the parameters that were passed to it. These compiled execution plans are cached so that the compiler does not have to recompile the stored procedure each time it is executed. The execution plan for the stored procedure will be reused in subsequent invocations, however this execution plan can be totally inefficient for other parameters. One way to deal with this is to specify `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` for your query.

> Other remarks

1. The `ORDER BY` clause is too wide and will probably hurt performance if the result set is large. You should consider creating Dynamic SQL to only sort on the columns that are actually needed.
2. You are using `@sp_search` to look up text in `first_log`, `last_log`, `platform` and `app`... That looks silly, what use case should find text in so many text columns that mean something different?
3. No indexes (at least you are not showing any). If you query the table you should provide suitable indexes to speed them up. Otherwise unless you are querying to find an ID you will be forcing a table scan.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer! I appreciate you effort. *Tips Hat*! May be others landing on this page might find it valuable like I found!